# how detect bot traffic in tomcat app on aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, tomcat, bots

We have a tomcat app running on EC2 and recently the app has stopped responding every now and then.  We've found that there is traffic coming from what appears to be a bot that runs the same search query every 100ms.  This traffic comes from different IP addresses.

Are there any tools we can consider to help detect and block this type of activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider using an application load balancer and web application firewall. If you turn your instances into an auto scaling group you’d be well on your way to a resilient scalable architecture.

Comment: Thanks, Chris.  We are using a load balancer and an AWS security group as the firewall.  I'm wondering if we could send activity logs to a service that would be able to detect that the same query is being made repeatedly and somehow block that activity in an automated manner.

Comment: @Erich You can add the a Web Application Firewall to that setup. The Security Group is your network level firewall, while the WAF is your application level firewall. You could then create a rule in WAF that would block a specific request, or you could get more involved with something like this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/tutorials-4xx-blocking.html As a side note, you should also consider adding a CDN in front of your application, and if you were using CloudFlare as your CDN you would have a WAF option there as well.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Chris and Mark!